# Get verified on YouTube as a person

Tags: youtube, google-plus

My friend created a Google+ profile for himself and a YouTube channel. I assisted him to verify his webpage on Google Web Master Tools and added Google Analytics to his page. He has 8k followers on his YouTube channel but cannot get a verified check on his page.

I did some research and Google says you need to have a Business profile as well. We created another Google+ page as his business but now we need to create another YouTube channel. This will destroy the follower count.

Is there a way to get verified as a person, not a company?

Comment: I found this [link](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/ytgplus) that you can ask Google about the issue I have at hand. I hope this help if someone needs help on the same issue.

Comment: I moved this up here to the comments because it doesn't really sufficiently answer the question.  If you can elaborate on the steps that you took to solve this specific problem, that would be fine as an answer.

Answer (score -2):

There are many networks on youtube that offer verification after a certain amount of subscribers. Most channels/pages link verifications. Contact your **youtube network provider** for more information.